# Display data from mysqllite database android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am new to database stuff in android. I want to know how can i get a row id for example NAME from my database. i have used the following with a bit of reasearch now i am stick on the displaying part.

```
       public class DestinateurTable {

                public String TABLE_NAME="destinateur";

                public String ROW_ID="rowid";
                public String NAME="name";
                public String AGENCE="agence";
                public String EMAIL="email";



            }


        public class Destinataire { 


            public String rowid,name,agence,email;


        }


    **My DBHelper.class**


    public class DBHelper {

    private final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/.../databases/";
    private final String DATABASE_NAME = "...sqlite";
    private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database = null;
    OpenHelper openHelper=null;
    StringBuilder query =null;
    Cursor cursor=null;

    DestinateurTable destinataireTable = new DestinateurTable();

    public static DBHelper dbHelper = null;

    private DBHelper(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    try {

        createDataBase();
        openDataBase();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context)
    {
    if(dbHelper == null)
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    return dbHelper;
    }

   public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException
    {
    openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    if(getDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnceFlag(context) == false){
        try {
        copyDataBase();
        setDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnceFlag(context);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

    }

    private class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        SQLiteStatement insertStmt;

        public OpenHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }


    public void setDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnceFlag(Context ctx)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnce", true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean getDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnceFlag(Context ctx)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        boolean isDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnce = prefs.getBoolean("isDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnce", false);
        return isDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnce; 
    }



    ////////////////////////////
    //// Write your methods here
    ////////////////////////////

    public ArrayList<Destinataire> getDestinataireList()
    {
        ArrayList<Destinataire> items=new ArrayList<Destinataire>();

        try
        {
            query = new StringBuilder();
            query.append("select * from "+destinataireTable.TABLE_NAME);

            cursor=this.database.rawQuery(query.toString(),null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    Destinataire d=new Destinataire();

                    d.rowid=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(destinataireTable.ROW_ID));
                    d.name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(destinataireTable.NAME));
                    d.agence=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(destinataireTable.AGENCE));
                    d.email=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(destinataireTable.EMAIL));

                    items.add(d);

                }

                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
            {
            cursor.close();

            }
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return items;
    }

    //--here
    public boolean addDestinataire(Destinataire d){
        this.database.beginTransaction();

        try{

            ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

            contentValues.put(destinataireTable.ROW_ID, d.rowid);
            contentValues.put(destinataireTable.NAME, d.name);
            contentValues.put(destinataireTable.AGENCE, d.agence);
            contentValues.put(destinataireTable.EMAIL, d.email);

            this.database.insert(destinataireTable.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

            this.database.setTransactionSuccessful();

        } catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

            return false;

        }   finally{

            this.database.endTransaction();

        }

        return true;
    }


    public boolean deleteDestinataire(String id){

        try {

            String query="delete from " + destinataireTable.TABLE_NAME+" where "+destinataireTable.ROW_ID+"='"+id+"'";
            this.database.execSQL(query);
        }

        catch(SQLiteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Salut! Cool de croiser des français par ici =) Je te conseil de lire ce tuto du site du zéro sur la base de donénes SQLite en Android : http://www.siteduzero.com/informatique/tutoriels/creez-des-applications-pour-android/les-bases-de-donnees

Comment: j'ai besoin d'une solution au plus vite

Comment: Faut poster plus de code si tu veux de l'aide. Ta question est floue.

Comment: C'est fait regarde ma question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your whole database operation seems to be fine. You mention that now you want to show the data.
The most common way of doing it is using a [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html), which is connected to an [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html), you could use the adapter directly with the Cursor, but you already got it as a List, so you can use the [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

To use it as a simple test and you start understand how it works. Create a new Activity that `extends ListActivity` and then you write the following code on it:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         ArrayList<Destinataire> items = getDestinataireList();
         ArrayAdapter<Destinataire> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Destinataire>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , android.R.id.text1, items)
         setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

also include this line inside the Destinataire class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + " " + agence + " " + email;
}
```

That's a very basic example and it's not optimised (for example, you should use a background thread to load data from the DB), but it should show a list with each item from your DB showing `name agence email`.

happy coding!

**edit:**

this line:

```
new ArrayAdapter<Destinataire>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , android.R.id.text1, items)
```

... have some important parts so let me explain:

- ArrayAdapter: it's standard behaviour is to call toString() for the objects in your Array, after you've done this first part, you can start studying about CustomAdapter, to make more complex (fun) stuff.
- this: That's reference the ListActivity. Every activity extends a ContextWrapper, that means that they hold reference to the device resources. Very important for adapters to create layouts.
- android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1: that's a standard Android layout that is just 1 line of text. Very simple, but good for quick testing. It's telling the adapter to use this layout on for each item.
- android.R.id.text1: it's the ID of the text inside the layout. It's telling the adapter that there's a TextView with that ID in the layout. So it will get toString() from the data objects and set it to the TextView
- items: that's your data.

Comment: yes but if i want to retrieve only name for example meaning a row in the database

Comment: the ArrayAdapter will be calling toString() on your Destinataire class. So you can just change the toString to whatever you need. I'll edit my answer now with a bit more explanation on the adapter. Please read.

Comment: i am getting a null pointer exeption.. I believe my database path is wrong.. is it the right way to take "/data/data/package_name/databases/ as DATABASE_PATH ?

Comment: it's a pretty big piece of code and the nullpointer might be happening on lots of different places. You have to read the log, it will tell you the exact line it's the error. Usually the path you can put just "mydb" because the method `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(` already puts it inside `/data/data/you.app.package/`